# Hive quering on existing table in HBase

Tags: hbase, hive

I've created table in HIVE using CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command for existing table in HBase.

I'm able to see the table through HIVE shell

but while querying on the table through HIVE, returns '0' records. Through logs identified that HIVE is executing MAP-REDUCE program in HADOOP and not in HBase

Have I missed anything in configuring Hive and HBase ?

Comment: Does the output of DESCRIBE EXTENDED Table look correct?

Comment: yes it looks correct, parameters information looks like this:   parameters:{EXTERNAL=TRUE, hbase.table.name=mytable, transient_lastDdlTime=1333741785, storage_handler=org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE)

Comment: The "External Table" defined by "Stored By" clause, should be able to access HBase table rows right? i'm able to access only those table records, that are added through Hive.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using a version of Hive before 0.9.

Creating a Hive table with HBase storage handler on Hive 0.8 and before will only allow you to access data from your HBase table that was inserted via your corresponding Hive table. If you had any pre-existing data in your HBase table that wasn't inserted through the Hive table, you wouldn't be able to query it through the Hive table either.

Starting Hive 0.9, [JIRA 1634](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1634), will be available which allows the Hive table to access all data present in the HBase table regardless of how it was inserted in it.

I suggest that you either get this patch or upgrade to Hive 0.9